# How do you code YouTube Contacts Feed request parameters

Tags: youtube-api

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_contacts#Retrieve_contacts

> *Note that the API returns a maximum of 100 contacts for any given contact feed request even if more contacts **match the request parameters**.*

Question: **How / Where do we define the request parameters** to narrow down a long list of contacts (100+) to a short list (<=100) ?

I would expect something like an authenticated request to:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/contacts?v=2&q=wildcard+querystring+wildcard`

or

`/feeds/api/users/default/contacts?v=2&fields=entry[yt:username: * da *]`

**and what is the wildcard (does asterics work)?**

Answer (score 1):

Given that the response includes the pagination info:

```
<openSearch:totalResults>4</openSearch:totalResults>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
```

You could page through the results. See [Paging through results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Paging_through_Results) in the docs.